# DefaultValueAttribute with uint

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, default-value, uint

I have a C# uint property decorated with the XmlElementAttribute and DefaultValueAttribute.

```
[XmlElement(typeof(uint), ElementName = "Delay")]
[DefaultValue(0)]
public uint Delay { get; set; }
```

When I try to use XSD to generate a schema for this type, it gives the following error:

> Object of type 'System.Int32' cannot be converted to type 'System.UInt32'.

I guess the issue may be that DefaultValueAttribute doesn't have a constructor which takes a uint as a paramter. How can I define the DefaultValue for an unsigned integer?

Answer (score 0):

```
[DefaultValue(typeof(uint), "0")]
```